# Is returning alias of variable from attr_reader secure?

Tags: ruby, oop

Firstly, let me introduce a code example:

```
class BankAccount
  attr_reader :allowed_users

  def initialize(allowed_users)
    @allowed_users = allowed_users
  end

end
```

so as we all know we can call `b = BankAccount.new %w( john alice )` to create `BankAccount` instance.

I don't want to have `attr_writer` (let's say to change `allowed_user` array I want to have some PIN code logic)

So now I can not call `b.allowed_users= %w( john annie )` but how ever I can call `b.allowed_users[1] = 'anie'` which will modify `@allowed_users` array.

How to deal with it? Is that how `attr_reader` was supposed to work or is it some kind of bug?

I know there is solution with `.freeze` method but what about

```
def allowed_users
  self.allowed_users.dup
end
```

which one is more efficient?

Comment: Where is the parenthesis opened at "**I don't want to have `attr_writer`(**" closed? Use correct capitalization. It is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

`attr_reader` just defines getter method for instance variable. So, in your case `b.allowed_users[1] = 'anie'` doesn't redefine instance variable `@allowed_users`, it just changes the object which address is saved in instance variable.

And you rightly pointed out, that's to solve this problem you need either use immutable object or write your own getter method, which doesn't return object directly.

I think that `freeze` fits better, because it explicitly throws an error, when you're trying to modify object:

```
2.1.1 :001 > arry = [1,2,3].freeze
 => [1, 2, 3] 
2.1.1 :002 > arry << 4
RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Array
```

Thus, if you're not familiar with class implementation, you'll not be able to make a possible mistake:

```
bank_account = BankAccount.new(User.limit(10))
bank_account.allowed_users << User.first
bank_account.allowed_users # at this step you expect to have allowed_users == User.take(10) + [User.last]
```